# remove table row from html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to remove a row from a table using jQuery. Here is the html:

```
<tr>
    <td><center><a id="remove" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></center></td>
</tr>
```

my jquery script:

```
$('td a').on('click',function(e){
//delete code.
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().remove();
```

});

when i click on the link, nothinh happens. Anybody can help me?

Comment: What do you see if you console.log(this) inside that handler?

Comment: Is your code in a document.ready() call? Side note, `<center>` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Have you verified the click is registering?  Also if you have more than one of the "remove" links, you should use `class="remove"` instead of `id="remove"` since there should only be one of each id on a page.

Comment: if i console.log(this) nothing happens in the console.

Comment: my code is in a $(document).ready(function(){

$('td a').on('click',function(e){
        //delete code.
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        console.log(this);
    });

});

Comment: Are any part of the `td a` created dynamically after the page is loaded?  The not logging of the this would seem to indicate that the elements that you are clicking do not have the binding on them.

Comment: yes, the td is created dynamically. what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either wrap your code in a `$(document).ready` call or move it to the end of the page before the closing body element (`</body>`). If you're executing that code in the head of your document you're running it against elements that don't yet exist.

Also if you want to remove the parent row, use `$(this).closest('tr')` instead of `$(this).parent()` as that would select the non-standard `<center>` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td a').on('click', function(e) {
    //delete code.
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1hddczrL/)**